# FUSB302 - Two devices, transmission between them

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, communication, usb-c

I have controller device with a [FUSB302](https://www.onsemi.com/products/interfaces/usb-type-c/fusb302) *Programmable USB Type-C Controller with PD* for power detection for charge battery.

I want to make a subdevice to emulate my own hardware. I know that FUSB302 can communicate by CC1/2 pins. After connect USB to controller, communication between the FUSB302 systems would take place, to detect my own device.

The questions are:

1. How can I emulate my device on the FUSB302? What registers to set?
2. How to set my controller to detect chargers as before, but also my own device?

The library I use is [PD_Micro](https://github.com/ryan-ma/PD_Micro), a "ATMega32U4 Arduino board with USB-C PD Power Delivery and PPS".

Comment: What exactly is the hardware you want to emulate?

Comment: 7V led light with photoresistor. After connecting my device, it has to be communication if it is my device. After getting along, the driver is to give 7V to the appropriate pins. Communication is to protect against burning another, accidentally connected device.